# Azure PowerShell Retrieve Cloud Classic Certificates

Tags: azure, powershell

I've been trying for some time to find a way to retrieve output from certificates at our Cloud Classic resource.

We have a Cloud Management Gateway which stores certs in a Cloud Service. As a part of monitoring that i would like to find a way of pulling out that data with powershell.

Anyone have any experience with this? Haven't been able yet to find anything that works.

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: I want to get expiration details of the certificates stored on the Cloud Service where we have our Cloud Management Gateway. The purpose is to use it as monitoring with a runbook powershell script so we can get a notification when a certificate is about to expire.
The problem is i haven't been able to find a way to extract these details after looking at several MS posts.

Comment: Is that the expired date of the Azure cloud service certificates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZzvf.png? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create#what-are-service-certificates

Comment: Yes exactly, i have looked at that article but it only shows how to create them. That's not what i'm interested in

Comment: Ok. I will do some test and research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the certificate from the Azure cloud service, we can use the command [`Get-AzureCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/get-azurecertificate?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

For example

1. create Run as account in azure automation account
2. Script

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"
      

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
if ($Conn -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
Write-Verbose "Getting the certificate: $CertificateAssetName" -Verbose
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
if ($AzureCert -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve certificate asset: $CertificateAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

Write-Verbose "Authenticating to Azure with certificate." -Verbose
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

$certs=Get-AzureCertificate -ServiceName testcloud05

foreach($cert in $certs){

  $result=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.Data))
  $result.Subject
  Get-Date $result.NotAfter -Format d

}
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"
      

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
if ($Conn -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
Write-Verbose "Getting the certificate: $CertificateAssetName" -Verbose
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
if ($AzureCert -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve certificate asset: $CertificateAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

Write-Verbose "Authenticating to Azure with certificate." -Verbose
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

$certs=Get-AzureCertificate -ServiceName "<your cloud service name>"

foreach($cert in $certs){

  $result=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.Data))
  $result.Subject
  Get-Date $result.NotAfter -Format d

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is what i'm looking for!
However i receive an error from the test pane of the runbook, that it does not know the terms:
Set-AzureSubscription
Select-AzureSubscription
Get-AzureCertificate

Currently trying to investigate why that is

Comment: @MathiasOttsen Could you please provide the error message?

Comment: `Set-AzureSubscription : The term 'Set-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:21 char:1
+ Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -Subsc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureSubscription:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Same goes for the other 2. Az module is loaded.

Comment: @MathiasOttsen HAve you installed the module Azure?

Comment: Yes i would assume it must be related to missing rights for the automatisation account. Anyways i would consider your help as being the answer to my question!
I wont be able to test it right away but i can see from the details that this is the outcome i seek :-)